# What is the best way to test ETLs- Source vs Target data comparision

Tags: testing, etl

The current set up that we have for testing ETLs is :

The target Datawarehouse Database is connected to the Source database through a linked server .

QA team has written a script which will read , transform the data from Source database and compare the result with the tables on the data warehouse , column by column for a sample of 100,000 records .

The company policy might take away the linked server connectivity , in which case , there will be  no connectivity between the source and target database to do the column by column comparision.

Is there any other way to do this without using any ETL tool ( because that is what being tested)

I can think of a third program like (Python etc) which sets up Database connections to both the Source and Target DBs , downloads the data and does a file comparision or something like that . Any better ideas ?

Are there any tools available for this type of testing ?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there are three ways to test this scenario:

i) Using Third Party Program ( Python/ Java)

ii) Manual (Stare & Compare / Download in csv and compare)

iii) Using ETL test Automation tools

Option (i) you have already mentioned.

Option ii) For some subset of data You can stare and compare the data between source & target databases. Or You can download samples of data from Source & Target in Excel and use macros for data comparison & validation. But as this involves manual steps, this will be time consuming & will not give good data coverage due to using samples.

Option iii) There are some licensed tools like Query Surge, BI Validator, DB Solo etc. available for data comparison and validation. DB Solo can do only DB to DB comparison. Also, you may not be able to verify complex transformations using DB Solo. Whereas, Query Surge & BI Validator can do DB to DB, DB to file, file to DB, file to file data comparison & validation. These may also help you to validate complex transformations if any between source & target data.

You can also use these tools for further data validation across different layers in your data warehouse and automate most of your ETL testing. To investigate your ETL tool options, check out this [wiki](https://www.etltools.net/wiki/).